# JOOQ connection Pool using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, activemq-classic, jooq

I am reading from activemq and running a stored procedure for the value got from activemq.

Since I am going to run for large volume at a regular rate we included Threading for reading message from activemq and running stored procedure.

After doing so I found that JOOQ is not using any connection pool and is running all SQL operations sequentially.

**JOOQ Log:**

```
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 03:27
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Fetched result           : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |loadoutputtobatchoutput|
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |                       |
15:30:51.843 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.844 [Thread-19973] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Finishing                : Total: 03:27, +0.272ms
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 03:27
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Fetched result           : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |loadoutputtobatchoutput|
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |                       |
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.856 [Thread-19975] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Finishing                : Total: 03:27, +0.267ms
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 03:28
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Fetched result           : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |loadoutputtobatchoutput|
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |                       |
15:30:51.905 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +-----------------------+
15:30:51.906 [Thread-19976] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Finishing                : Total: 03:28, +0.256ms
15:30:51.938 [Thread-19977] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 03:28
```

**Gradle Build to initialize JOOQ:**

```
jooq {
   csmart(sourceSets.main) {
      jdbc {
         driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
         url = 'jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:8000/XXX'
         user = 'XXX'
         password = 'XXX'
         schema = 'public'
      }
      generator {
         name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
         strategy {
            name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
         }
         database {
            name = 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
            inputSchema = 'public'
            customTypes {
               customType {
                  name = 'JsonElement'
                  type = 'com.google.gson.JsonElement'                 
                  converter = 'XXX'
               }
            }
            forcedTypes {
               forcedType {
                  name = 'JsonElement'
                  expression = 'public\\.batchoutput\\.batchoutput_json|public\\.batchinput\\.batchinput_json'                           
               }
            }
         }
         generate {
           // relations = false
           //records = false            
           // pojos = true  
           // daos = true         
         }
         target {
            packageName = 'XXX'
            directory = 'jooq'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**JOOQ Connection Class:**

```
package com.check.orchestrator.di.configuration;

import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
       "check.dal.jooq.tables.daos"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBContextConfiguration {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD = "db.password";    
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_JOOQ_SQL_DIALECT = "sql.dialect";
    private Properties properties;  

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {        
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        properties = new Properties();      

        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/config.properties"));          
        }
        catch (IOException e) {         
        }

        dataSource.setDriverClass(properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD));      

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnectionDataSource() {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
        return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyConnectionDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(lazyConnectionDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
    }   

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

        jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());        

        String sqlDialectName = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_JOOQ_SQL_DIALECT);        
        SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(sqlDialectName);
        jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

        return jooqConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dslContext() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }  

}
```

Comment: How do you configure your jOOQ `Configuration` / `DSLContext` (note, the code generation configuration probably doesn't help here)

Comment: @LukasEder Sorry for inconvenience I have added the connection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a question related to jOOQ but one related to BoneCP and its default configuration. You didn't specify how many connection you would like to have in your pool, so the default will apply - which is probably not enough.

The BoneCP documentation isn't super specific about its defaults, but you can easily reverse engineer this from `com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig`. The relevant attributes are:

```
/** Min number of connections per partition. */
private int minConnectionsPerPartition = 1;
/** Max number of connections per partition. */
private int maxConnectionsPerPartition = 2;
/** Number of partitions. */
private int partitionCount = 1;
```

So, by default, your connection pool will have a maximum of 2 connections. Not too impressive.